# How to autogenerate Timestamp in SQLite RoomDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room, android-jetpack

I was creating entity class for RoomDatabase in Android Studio To define Table. I don't know how autogenerate timestamp in Entity. Is there any annotation available like @PrimaryKey(autogenerate=true)?

```
@Entity(tableName = "userTable")
public class DataEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requirement")
    private String requirement;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    private String timestamp;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help

```java
@Entity(tableName = "userTable")
public class DataEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requirement")
    private String requirement;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    private String timestamp = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));

}
```